# How to use CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql

```
select 
    SUBSTRING(ackey,1,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(ackey, 3,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(ackey,8,6)
from 
    tHE_Move
where case 
        when acDocType in ('1900', '1910', '1920', '1930') then acWayOfSale <> 'E'
        when acDocType in ('1950', '1960') then acWayOfSale <> 'U'
```

Can I do something like this?

I solved this with:

```
select 
    SUBSTRING(ackey,1,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(ackey, 3,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(ackey,8,6)
from 
    tHE_Move
where 
    (case when acDocType in ('1900', '1910', '1920', '1930') then acWayOfSale end <> 'E'
    or
    case when acDocType in ('1950','1960') then acWayOfSale end <> 'U')
```

But I'm interested if this can be solved in only one case?

Comment: You don't really need `case` here - just combine the pieces of logic together using `AND` and `OR`. `CASE` is meant to be an *expression* that returns a *value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
where acWayOfSale <> case when acDocType in ('1900', '1910', '1920', '1930') then 'E'
                     when acDocType in ('1950', '1960') then 'U'
                     else ...
                     end
```

(Or of course create/modify a table with the `acDocType` values and the desired character and `JOIN` to it)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but `CASE` returns an expression and in tsql cannot return a boolean.. What you really want to do is use a combination of `AND` and `OR`. In your case:

```
where (acDocType in ('1900', '1910', '1920', '1930') and acWayOfSale <> 'E')
or (acDocType in ('1950','1960') and acWayOfSale <> 'U')
```